# Simple program to return all factors of a given input integer

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a simple program to return all factors of a given input integer. factors of 32 with while loop array Unfortunately I am stuck.

**Code**

```
Dim x As Integer
x = txtInput.Text
Dim factor As Integer
factor = CInt(txtInput.Text) - 1
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
While factor > 0
    Do Until i = x
        If factor * i = x Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(factor)
            i = i + 1
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
    factor = factor - 1
End While
```

Comment: "Unfortunately I am stuck" is *not* a very good bug report :-) You should include the minimal code sample (yes, you've done this), what you expect (ditto) and what actually happens (not really). You need to elaborate.

Comment: Hints: you should use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx); you only need to check for factors up to half the input value; if `x mod y = 0` then y is a factor of x.

Comment: Even if your code worked a number's factors are endless.

Comment: @BanForFun Not if you use the conventional meanings of "a number's factors" and "endless".